# Debugging azure python durable function on vscode

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have faithfully followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=linux%2Cazure-cli-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-configuration) on how to create a python durable function and everything went well.

However able to start the project from the CLI, within the context of **virtual env**, I am unable to start **vscode** debugging.

Vscode python interpreter was set to the one inside **.env**, but consistently I get `ModuleNotFoundError`, more specifically the module `'azure.durable_functions'` -surely installed- when starting debug.

---

**requirements.txt**

```
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true
        }
    ]
}
```

---

This issue was reproduced in two different Windows machines and an Ubuntu one.

Python version: 3.11
Vscode version: latest and 1.77.3

Comment: which python interpreter you are using here?

Comment: the one inside env/Scripts/python.exe created by venv.

Comment: When you are creating durable function, which python interpreter you are selecting?

Comment: I got you, I am probably using one of the global ones on my machines as I just created the venv afterwards.

Comment: Can you tell me which one you are selecting among the global ones?

Comment: I noticed that I have actually skipped this step while creating the function. I preferred to create the virtual env manually, however, just realized that when creating from within vscode it properly creates the debugging configuration file. All working fine now. Appreciate your comments tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing the process, I realized I had skipped a step while creating the function project through vscode. More specifically:

> In Visual Studio Code, press F1 (or Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P) to open the
> command palette. In the command palette, search for and select Azure
> Functions: Create New Project....

However, when initializing the project from within VSCode it automatically generates the necessary debugging configuration files.

As I have created the function projects from the CLI I didn't find it necessary to "recreate" things from the IDE. Anyhow, this resolved the debugging issue.

---

Updated debugging files:

**settings.json**

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
  "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
  "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".env",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

**task.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "func",
      "label": "func: host start",
      "command": "host start",
      "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
    },
    {
      "label": "pip install (functions)",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.json** and **extensions.json** remains the same. Thanks @ikhtesam for your insights.